# WSO2 API manager - Unable to publish API built on Node using Sails

Tags: sails.js, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I've followed the procedure to publish an API using the GUI, I've mapped my node implementation URL to a WSO2 URL.

For example:
api_host:api_port/myapp
was mapped to:
wso2_host:wso2_port/wso2api/v1/

Then I published the API, which was then visible in app store.

This was followed by an application subscribing to the API, generating keys and all proceeded as expected.

Finally, I go to a browser and issue a GET request on wso2_host:wso2_port/wso2api/v1/ after using the correct access token in the header.

What I receive in the response is "404 Not Found".

I've tried many permutations and combinations, am I missing some step?

Comment: I just found out the reason. In fact, the same issue was faced [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472308/wso2-esb-doesnt-process-put-request-from-api-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 indicates that resource not fund. Can you cheek your request URL is right?

```
Eg: http://localhost:8280/test/1.0
```

Comment: I had to modify the XML file generated by deleting the POST_TO_URI entry.